# How to read and write numpy arrays to protected file

Tags: python, numpy, io, locking

I would like several processes running in parallel to read and write to the same numpy array.  To avoid problems, where two processes try to read/write to the same memory, I need to protect the file I am writing to.  How do I do that?

I assume that `np.savetxt` does not protect the file.  I have tried the library `portalocker`.  But by opening a file and locking it, `np.savetxt` is not allowed to write to the file.

Comment: Reading from the same file is not a problem. Why do they need to write to the same file?

Comment: @user5402 to coordinate their work.

Comment: You can organize the parallelism so each process writes its results to a different file. For example, see Fork-join parallelism [(link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_model).

Comment: Maybe something like that is easier.  I want a process to see what values in an array have not been computed yet, so that it can start a computation that has not been run already.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question "Downloading over 1000 files in python" (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160982/downloading-over-1000-files-in-python/27161254#27161254) for examples of using a worker thread pool.

Basically you split up all of the work beforehand, put the work into a queue and let a pool of worker threads process each piece of work. The workers put the results onto a another queue which can be processed by another thread to put all of the pieces together.

Comment: How do I use a queue if the processes are running on different computers?

Comment: You can't, but you might be able to use [the dispy library](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/).