# How to address RuntimeError: can't start new thread using Selenium for webscraping?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, runtime-error, threadpool

I have built a script to collect products and the details of them from many websites (~120). It does what I would like to achieve, but after some time (mainly around 70 pages) it gives me a "MemoryError", and a "RuntimeError: can't start new thread". I have tried to look for solutions, like: .clear() my lists, or try to use sys.getsizeof() to spot the memory leaks, but no success, yet. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

The detailed error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
main()

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) # execute the script

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "C:/EGYÉB/PYTHON/Projects/WebScraping/Selenium_scraping.py", line 63, in <module>
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 679, in page_source
return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 423, in _request
data = utils.load_json(data.strip())

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\utils.py", line 37, in load_json
return json.loads(s)

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\Python Core\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\Python Core\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\Python Core\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
MemoryError

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1505, in do_it
t.start()

File "C:\EGYÉB\PYTHON\Python Core\lib\threading.py", line 847, in start
_start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import time
import re

os.chdir('C:\...')
price = []
prod_name = []
href_link = []
specs = []
item_specs1 = []
item_specs2 = []
url1 = 'https://login.aliexpress.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url1)
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.frame('alibaba-login-box')
driver.find_element_by_id('fm-login-id').send_keys('..........')
driver.find_element_by_id('fm-login-password').send_keys('.........')
driver.find_element_by_id('fm-login-submit').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.default_content()

df = pd.read_csv('........csv', header=0)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    page_nr = 1
    url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/store/{}'.format(row['Link']) + '/search/{}'.format(page_nr) + '.html'
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    for page_number in count(start=1):
        time.sleep(5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        for div_b in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'cost'}):
            price.append(div_b.text + 'Ł')
        for pr_name in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'detail'}):
            for pr_h in pr_name.find_all('h3'):
                for pr_title in pr_h.find_all('a'):
                    prod_name_t = (pr_title.get('title').strip())
                    prod_name_l = (pr_title.get('href').strip())
                    href_link.append(prod_name_l + 'Ł')
                    prod_name.append(prod_name_t + 'Ł')
                    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='node-gallery']/div[5]/div/div/ul/li/div[2]/h3/a")]
                    for link in links:
                        driver.get(link)
                        time.sleep(2)
                        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
                        for item1 in soup1.find_all('span', {'class': 'propery-title'}):
                            item_specs1.append(item1.text)
                        for item2 in soup1.find_all('span', {'class': 'propery-des'}):
                            item_specs2.append(item2.text + 'Ł')
                        item_specs = list(zip(item_specs1, item_specs2)))
                        item_specs_join = ''.join(str(item_specs))
                        item_specs_replace = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n.:Ł]', '', item_specs_join)]
                        specs.append(item_specs_replace)
                        item_specs1.clear()
                        item_specs2.clear()
                        soup1.clear()
                        driver.back()
                    links.clear()
        if len(prod_name) > 500:
            data_csv = list(zip(prod_name, price, href_link, specs))
            with open('........csv'), 'a', newline='') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                for row0 in data_csv:
                    writer.writerow(row0)
            f.close()
            price.clear()
            prod_name.clear()
            href_link.clear()
            specs.clear()
            data_csv.clear()
        try:
            if soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'ui-pagination-next ui-pagination-disabled'}):
                print("Last page reached!")
                break
            else:
                driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-pagination-next').click()
                time.sleep(1)
        except Exception:
            break
driver.quit()
data_csv = list(zip(prod_name, price, href_link, specs))
print(len(data_csv))
with open('.......csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row1 in data_csv:
        writer.writerow(row1)
f.close()
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace

Comment: Done. Hope you meant that.

Comment: It is still an open question. Every help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

...implies that the system "can't start new thread" as you already have too many threads running within your python process and due to a resource limit the request to create a new thread is refused.

Your main issue is stems out from the line:

```
item_specs_join = ''.join(str(item_specs))
```

You need to look at the number of threads your program is creating against the maximum number of threads your system is capable of creating depending on your environment. Possibly your program is starting more threads than that which can be handled by your system. There is a limit to the number of threads that can be active for one process.

Another factor may be, your program is starting threads faster than the threads are running to completion. If you need to start many threads you need to do it in a more controlled manner you can use a thread pool.

It would be a better approach to re-design the flow of the program considering that the threads are running asynchronously. Perhaps using a pool of threads to fetch resources while starting up a thread for every request.

You can find a detailed discussion on [error: can't start new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834919/error-cant-start-new-thread)

Here you will also find a detailed discussion on [Is there any way to kill a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread)