# Problem when checking connection with mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(host= "localhost", port= 27017)
print(client)
```

Can anyone help me?
When running these two lines, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown
```

I asked everyone, they didn't know the problem

Comment: Try to see [error: can't start new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834919/error-cant-start-new-thread)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834919/error-cant-start-new-thread