pip install failing in azurelinux based docker image
We are using mcr.microsoft.com/azurelinux/base/python:3.12.3-4-azl3.0.20241101-amd64 as our base image to build python based application . but when we are performing docker build from a ubuntu18 or 22 based host machine, with the pip command inside the dockerfile, we are getting below error. But when we execute the build from rhel8 host machine its working.
   Downloading pygments-2.18.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.5 kB)
 Collecting mdurl~=0.1 (from markdown-it-py>=2.2.0->rich>=10.11.0->typer>=0.12.3->fastapi-cli>=0.0.5->fastapi-cli[standard]>=0.0.5; extra == "standard"->fastapi[standard]==0.115.5->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
   Downloading mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
 Downloading fastapi-0.115.5-py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
 Downloading httpx-0.27.2-py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
 Downloading langchain-0.3.7-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
 [91mERROR: Exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 105, in _run_wrapper
     status = _inner_run()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 96, in _inner_run
     return self.run(options, args)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 67, in wrapper
     return func(self, options, args)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 379, in run
     requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 179, in resolve
     self.factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirements_more(reqs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 554, in prepare_linked_requirements_more
     self._complete_partial_requirements(
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 469, in _complete_partial_requirements
     for link, (filepath, _) in batch_download:
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 184, in __call__
     for chunk in chunks:
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 54, in _rich_progress_bar
     with progress:
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/progress.py", line 1168, in __enter__
     self.start()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/progress.py", line 1159, in start
     self.live.start(refresh=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/live.py", line 132, in start
     self._refresh_thread.start()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 992, in start
     _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
 RuntimeError: can't start new thread
 [0mThe command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2

requirement.txt
fastapi[standard]==0.115.5
httpx==0.27.2
langchain==0.3.7
langchain-core==0.3.19
langchain_community==0.3.2
langchain-openai==0.2.9
langchain-text-splitters==0.3.2
logger==1.4
openai==1.54.5
pandas==2.2.3
pydantic==2.9.2
pydantic_core==2.23.4
pytest==8.3.3
pytest-cov==6.0.0
pytest-integration-mark==0.2.0
pytest-mock==3.14.0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
requests==2.32.3
rank-bm25==0.2.2
six==1.16.0

Dockerfile as below
mcr.microsoft.com/azurelinux/base/python:3.12.3-4-azl3.0.20241101-amd64
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app
COPY ./pip.conf ~/.pip/

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
..............
.............


"RuntimeError: can't start new thread" means not enough RAM. Or not enough limits to create threads, see ulimit.

Sorry to miss that I missed to mention that Ubuntu host is docker container configured as AzureDevops agent.  I checked by ulimit command getting output as "unlimited". what its means?

Docs: https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh, read ulimit. Try  ulimit -Ha  and ulimit -Sa. See the limits for memory and threads.

If the limits are big enough — you simply don't have enough RAM in the container. free -h?

limit are too big and RAM 31 GB is available

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76833922/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22RuntimeError%22+%22can%27t+start+new+thread%22
